# PyQt Open File Dialog error

Tags: python, pyqt, xlrd

So, I have an application with a QTableWidget and want to import an .xls file:

```
def openfile(self):
        filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', '/home', ".xls(*.xls)")
        fname = open(filename)
        with fname:
            wb = xlrd.open_workbook(fname)
            wb.sheet_names()
            sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
            for col in sh.ncols:
                for i in col:
                    r = 0
                    c = 0
                    newItem = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(i)
                    self.tableWidget.setItem(r, c, newItem)
                    r += 1
                r = 0
                c += 1
```

But, I get this error: `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found`

What have I done wrong?

**Update:**

```
def openfile(self):
            filename = unicode(QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', '', ".xls(*.xls)"))
            wb = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
            wb.sheet_names()
            sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
            self.first = sh.col_values(0)
            self.r = 0
            self.add()

    def add(self):
        for i in self.first:
             str(i)
             newItem = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(i)
             self.tableWidget.setItem(self.r, 0, newItem)
             self.r += 1
```

It's working, but I can't load numbers...
Only strings...
Weird...

**Update2:**

```
def add(self):
        for i in self.first:
             newItem = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(i))
             self.tableWidget.setItem(self.r, 0, newItem)
             self.r += 1
```

But it displays all numbers as floats....

**Update3:**

```
def add(self):
        for i in self.first:
             try:
                newItem = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(int(i)))
             except ValueError:
                newItem = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(i))    
             self.tableWidget.setItem(self.r, 0, newItem)
             self.r += 1
```

Problem solved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[xlrd.open_wookbook](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html#xlrd.open_workbook-function) expects a filename (a string), not `fname` (a file object).

Try:

```
        filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', '/home', ".xls(*.xls)")
        wb = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
```

Comment: Now I get this:  filestr = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), size, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
ValueError: mmap offset is greater than file size

Comment: You could get this error if `size` is greater than the file size of `f`. If that does not help, please open a new question and show how `f` and `size` are defined in more detail.

Comment: @Antoni4040. Works for me when passing a filename (even a `QString`) as first argument to `xlrd.open_workbook`. Have you checked that the file you are using is a valid `xls` file? Try passing the file contents in directly, like this: `xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=open(filename).read())`.

Comment: @Antoni4040. If you look at the constructors for [`QTableWidgetItem`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qtablewidgetitem.html#QTableWidgetItem) you'll see that passing an `int` as the first argument will be interpreted as the item's type, rather than its contents.

Comment: Yes, but had I converted it to a string... What else can I do?

Comment: Solved it completely! Thanks a lot for your help, unutbu!